# which touch event to use to slide an image?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

i am using the following function to move a ball from one location to another wherever user touches the screen..right now i dont have an i-phone to test my application and i am new to i-phone application programming so i wanted to know does this event will also make the ball slide from one point to another wen user maintains the touch??

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

{

UITouch *touch=[[event allTouches] anyObject];
 CGPoint location=[touch locationInView:touch.view];
 fball.center=location;
}

Answer (score 0):

Implement `-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` and `-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`